# Make big query from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

```
profiles (id, name, deleted)
categories (id, name, deleted)
profiles_categories (id, profile_id, category_id, , deleted)
```

How i can select all `profiles` with `name` in categories?

I trying something like this, but its not works...

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p 
JOIN categories c, profiles_categories pc 
WHERE p.id = pc.profile_id 
  AND WHERE pc.id = c.category_id
```

Thanks

EDIT

```
SELECT *
FROM profiles p 
INNER JOIN profiles_categories pc 
  ON p.id = pc.profile_id 
INNER JOIN categories c
  ON pc.id = c.id
```

its return only for one `profile` (now only two active `profiles`, but only first have `categories`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several issues with your current query.

First, you are mixing join types.  You should use ANSI JOIN syntax between all of the tables. Don't mix ANSI JOIN syntax with some tables and then commas between other tables.

Second, you have two WHERE clauses and you can only have one WHERE clause.

Finally, you should include the column names that you want to return instead of `SELECT *`

The query should be similar to this:

```
SELECT p.name, c.name
FROM profiles p 
INNER JOIN profiles_categories pc 
  ON p.id = pc.profile_id 
INNER JOIN categories c
  ON pc.id = c.category_id
```

An INNER JOIN between the tables will return all rows that exist in all of the tables.

Note, based on your table structure you might be able to use the following which returns the profiles that have a corresponding row in the the `profiles_categories` table:

```
select p.name
from profiles p
where p.id in (select profile_id
               from profiles_categories);
```

Edit you want to return all profiles regardless of whether or not then have a category, then you need to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT p.name, c.name
FROM profiles p 
LEFT JOIN profiles_categories pc 
  ON p.id = pc.profile_id 
LEFT JOIN categories c
  ON pc.id = c.category_id
```

Comment: @Alex JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN, just so you know.
+1 for the extra effort bluefeet

Comment: Yes, its works nice, but this code get ONLY first `profile`, look EDIT.. now i add

Comment: @AlexKiselev If you want to return all of the profiles, even if there is not a category with it, then you will use a LEFT JOIN. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p 
JOIN profiles_categories pc on p.id = pc.profile_id 
JOIN categories c on pc.id = c.category_id
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p, categories c, profiles_categories pc 
WHERE p.id = pc.profile_id 
  AND pc.id = c.category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles p 
JOIN profiles_categories pr on p.id = pr.profile_id 
JOIN categories c on pr.id = c.category_id
WHERE c.name='thename'
```